# Parse a json {"result": DIFFERENTS TYPES}} using differents types nested in the result

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to know how I can use a {"result": {}} json with diferents types, I don't have any idea how to construct the class or reused a class Result.

Answer (score 1):

Think of it as having a `Map<String, dynamic>` before parsing it as encoding/decoding it as JSON. This would allow you to have the following structure:

```
{
    "result": {
        "int": 2,
        "String": "Sting vaue",
        "bool": true
    }
}
```